# How to get scalar product from geometric product in Geometric Algebra?

Tags: geometric-algebras

I read that geometric product $ab$ can be decomposed into 2 parts (symmetric and antisymmetric).

But I can't understand why symmetric part is a scalar product.

I mean following symmetric part:

$\frac{1}{2} (ab+ba) = \frac{1}{2}((a+b)^2-a^2-b^2)$

Why $ab+ba = (a+b)^2-a^2-b^2$ and $\frac{1}{2} (ab+ba) = a \cdot b $ ?

Thanks.

Comment: Expand $(a+b)^2$ using the distributive property and remember that $v^2 = |v|^2 = v\cdot v$ for any vector $v$.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Thanks! $(a+b)^2 = (a+b)(a+b)$